# Color Mixing and Separation

Tags: image, image-processing, colors

Assume that I have 2 layers each containing only 1 bit (for simplicity)

```
Layer0 bit = 1 (I'll color this red (255, 0, 0))
Layer1 bit = 0 (I'll color this green (0, 255, 0))
```

Now, I want to add the colors in these two layers and discard the two Layers.

```
Resultant Layer = (255, 255, 0)
```

I know that this layer contains one 1 and one 0. But how do I know what's the order of this, i.e. `0 1` or `1 0` (originally it was `1 0`, but during decryption, it can be recognized as `0 1`).
Can anybody help me with this?
Edit: Can this be done with the help of CDMA?

Comment: if you only have 2 layers all the time, you can use subtraction. You can store it in a variable `checkSub` in your `Resultant` class; if it's `-1` then it's decrypted as `0 1`, and `1` is decrypted as `1 0`

Comment: Layers are not limited. They can be 2, they can be many more. Although I didn't get your concept of subtraction. In your case, I'll subtract what from what to get -1 and 1?

Comment: `0-1=-1` and `1-0=1`; I see.. this wouldn't work with layers >2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able recognize order of layers you need to somehow store that information within the `relustant`class.

**First approach:**
easiest way wold be to have class attribute that will store this information in form of list, array or something.

**Second approach:** 
If your `relustant` constructor takes params as integers and you have only small number of layers lets say 5 you could encode this information like this (if you have more layers you can use decimal notation 254.0 + layer position and when drawing color would be rounded up):

> colors would be 250 instead of 255 and you will add layer number to this color so in your example final layer would be (250,251,0) with more layers you need to implement more complex logic behind decoding.

**Third approach:** 
In real life you would like to add different colors (with other values then 255 and 0) then its is more complicated but here is some basic look.

> You have values from 0 to 255 that add together and will never get over 255 so you will use bite shifting and you will shift each value according to layer order. To demonstrate this i will use values from 0 to 9. For example 
>   L0 = 2
>   L1 = 0
>   L2 = 3
>   The result should be 203 and will represent 5 (simple add all basic values 2 + 0 + 3) but from number 203 you are capable to decode order of layers. Because first you will add layer with value 2 to result (result = 2) now you need to shift number by base (result = 20) now add value of next layer and so on ... using bite shift it would be where base would be 8 because of max value 255. Layer is it's position.

```
result = result<<base*layer | value
```

Hope it is understandable and it will help you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help.As per what I understand from your third approach example the resultant color obtained will be 5 (obtained by adding the digits 2+0+3 in the end result 203) but while decrypting it how can I get back the 203 from 5 is what I'm unable to understand. While decrypting, 5 can be decoded as 1+0+4 or maybe 0+2+3

Comment: The "trick" is that you pass value 203 as parameter and then inside function you calculate value 5 and set color. And when you want to decode you use stored value 203 which can be easily decoded by digits. But using 8bit values (0-255) you can't see it as digits but as bits ...